# Can Flyway create database if not exited?

Tags: mysql, flyway

Can Flyway create database if not exited?
Database Migration 
but can not create database auto can it?

or could someone tell me which property can active this feature

Comment: This heavily depends on the DBMS being used. In Postgres and SQL Server this can typically only be done by a DBA. In Oracle it's more than just a simple SQL command. So, no I doubt that flyway can do that. Except for MySQL where databases are in fact schemas

Comment: flyway can do it by execute init sql or configuration.
and config spring.datasource.url like this alse can archive purpose
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${spring.datasource.name}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

Comment: yes MySQL 5.7.19, I implements my project can deploy to any new machine and can redeploy after delete old database, it still can stay at the same db version

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is no, Flyway expects to be able to make a JDBC connection to an existing database.

What is your use case? Are you really looking to combine Flyway with some sort of DB provisioning tool? Have a look at https://flywaydb.org/blog/flyway-provisioning .

Comment: flyway can do it by execute init sql or configuration.
and config spring.datasource.url like this alse can archive purpose
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${spring.datasource.name}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

Comment: Julia's point is valid though. Even if it is possible by SQL, you shouldn't do it.